# php jsonparsing error no data on browser

Tags: php, json

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "alsmwsk3", "skrktkzl12", "alsmwsk3");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from NOTICE ORDER BY noticeDate DESC");
$response = array();

$num = 0;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response, array("noticeContent"=>$row[0],"noticeName"=>$row[1],"noticeDate"=>$row[2]));
    echo $num;                                 
}

//php를 읽었을떄 json타입이 아닐 readed php not but json?
//print (json_encode($response));
//    echo json_encode(array("response"));

echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

when I open this phpsource on browser there are no data on browser I think am i wrong some kind of miss?

[image: open on browser but not data]

and it is mysql setting

[image: Mysql database table]

Comment: Try viewing your log files, /var/log/apache2/error.log or enable error output in the browser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Why output "0" 3 times? - just curious...

Comment: I cringe whenever I see `SELECT *` and then numeric indexes in `$row`. The code will break if the order of columns ever changes in the table. Use associative arrays.

Comment: Then how should i do?